# Are the Experience Manager link instructions configurable?

Tags: experience-manager, configuration

When adding or removing links to standalone links in Experience Manager, authors may see instructions, including the following:

- `<add external link>`
- `<add internal link to multimedia content>`
- `<add internal link to content>`

I understand these are simply part of Experience Manager, but want to confirm these instructions have nothing to do with the "dummy" (Lorem Ipsum) type text we would include in content types.

Are these instructions configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values come straight out of the resource bundle (`Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.dll` in `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin`) so they are unfortunately not user adjustable.

Comment: Thanks, Bart. I should have made a bet with those that were debating this with me (I would have awarded the beer to you!).